# How to generate md5 of file in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, md5

I have code, which generate md5 for strings.
Now I want to add generation md5 for files.
It work's with txt files(xml, html, txt etc), but when I try to do it with binary file(zip, bin, apk, etc) I see wrong result.
How can I correctly read bin file in (char*) in order to generate valid hash?

I tried to use TextStream, but result is not valid

```
QFile file(fileName);
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

QTextStream in(&file);
QString t = in.readAll();
file.close();

string res = md5(t.toStdString());
```

Also I tried to use QByteArray and after that convert byteArray to char*
But it doesn't work correctly too.
How can I fix it?

Comment: *Never ever use `QString` and `QTextStream` for binary data*. They are for Unicode text, decoded from bytes in a well-known encoding. Trying to use them for binary data will happily and silently screw it up.

Comment: Ok, but what can I use in order to do it?

Comment: You may want to consider QCrytographicHash. Qt has builtin md5 generation.  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcryptographichash.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Never ever use `QString` and `QTextStream` for binary data.*** They are for Unicode text, decoded from bytes in a well-known encoding. Trying to use them for binary data will happily and silently screw it up, as `QString` by default will try to interpret the input data using some encoding to translate it to its UTF-16 storage, silently skipping whatever it cannot understand.

The class for storing binary data is `QByteArray`, and you can read a whole file in it using the `QFile::read()` method.

```
QByteArray data;
{
    QFile file(fileName);
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    data.readAll();
}

string res = md5(std::string(data.begin(), data.end());
```

Notice that I built the `std::string` with the range-based constructor, since just using `std::string(data.data())` (constructor from a C string) would stop at the first embedded NUL.

Comment: I tried to use QByteArray, but I got wrong result too :(
So, I think it is a problem with my md5 implementation.
But for strings and txt files it works

Comment: Let's see your code... you can get it wrong with `QByteArray` too if you don't do as I did (e.g. you don't build the `std::string` with the range-based constructor).

Comment: Oh, sorry,
your Code works, thank you)